# C : Load data from file to the linked list

Tags: c, file, file-io, struct, linked-list

I wrote a program to create a simple dictionary. I want to save the dictionary data to a file and when I run the program next time I want to load that data into the linked list.

**This is my code:**

```
struct node{   //structure for dictionary
    char word[20];
    char meaning[5][100]; //to store max five meanings
    struct node *next;
};

//This is how I'm saving data to the file. I guess it's working, because size of the file increases..

void WriteData(struct node *head)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("dictionary.data", "wb");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file..\n");
        return;
    }
    while(head != NULL)
    {
        fwrite(head->word, sizeof(head->word), 1, fp);
        fwrite(head->meaning, sizeof(head->meaning), 1, fp);
        head = head->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

But how to read file and load the data back into the linked list?

Comment: `sizeof(head->word)` is exactly 20, which is the length of the word..

Comment: please be aware that there might be some extra data after the "\0" char which might contain some sensitive information, be careful in correctly zeroing your dictionary data.

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: if I'll use `strlen` instead of `sizeof` every chunk of data will have different size.. Then how do I read it to load that data back into the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You used fwrite() function, use fread() now :)**
Here is a pseudo code. Leaving converting to C/C++ and error handling to you.

```
node *head - nullptr;
node **tail = &head;
while (not end of file)
{
  *tail = allocate_and_nullify_memory();
  fread((*tail)->word, size_of_head_word, 1, fp);
  fread((*tail)->meaning, size_of_meaning, 1, fp);
  //Move the insertion point
  tail = &(*tail)->next;
}
```

Comment: BTW: `tail = &tail->next;` -->> `tail = &(*tail)->next;`

Comment: @joop Yes, sure. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

in order you have to:

1) read a file with fgets/getline/read/fread functions;

2) for every single line readed you have to add it to your list, example:

```
while (read(fd, buffer, dim) > 0) {
    struct node* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    strncpy(tmp->word, buffer, dim);
    tmp->next = NULL;
    last->next = tmp;
    last = last-> next;
}
```

Where buffer contains your line, and last is the pointer to last element of the list.

Comment: Wrong. You have structure members alignment problem. `std::cout << sizeof(node::meaning) << ", " << sizeof(node::word) << ", " << sizeof(node) <<"\n";` gives `500, 20, 528`